# How to check what character an item in a list is?

Tags: python, list

I'm new to coding and needed some help with this issue. I want my code to check what character an item is in a list and return a number corresponding to that letter's position in the alphabet. For example, if the first item in my list was "A", I'd want to have it return "0". I could do this with a long series of if else statements but I don't really want to write spaghetti code like that. Any help? In case it is of use, here is my code so far:

```
#Ceasar Cipher Decipherer

import time

listchar = 0
alphanum = 0

def Convert(string): 
    list1=[] 
    list1[:0]=string 
    while " " in list1:
      list1.remove(" ")
    return list1

alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
coded_phrase = input("Enter the encoded phrase now.\n")
jumps_forward = input("Enter the number of times the decoder must jump forwards in the alphabet.\n")

print("Thanks! Decoding phrase...\n")
time.sleep(0.5)

Convert(coded_phrase)

while listchar <= len(coded_phrase):
  #this is where I want the alphabet-checky code thing to go.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only care about lower letters you can use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```
def pos_in_alphabet(char):
    return ord(char) - ord("a")

print(pos_in_alphabet("a"))  # 0
print(pos_in_alphabet("b"))  # 1
print(pos_in_alphabet("c"))  # 2

print(pos_in_alphabet("x"))  # 23
print(pos_in_alphabet("y"))  # 24
print(pos_in_alphabet("z"))  # 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
alphabet.index("g")
6
```

You need to use the `.index()` method on the list

Answer (score 0):

Check this code and see if is this what you want:

```
array = ["a", "b", "y", "z", "A", "B", "Y", "Z"]

for i in array:
    print( ord( i.upper() ) - ord("A") )
```